# How to modify and add comment to xml

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm trying to modify an xml file using groovy and I'm stuck with adding a simple comment in between. How can I change person's name and add a comment to the root of the xml?

xml I'm reading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <name>John</name>
</person>
```

xml I want to output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- comment -->
<person>
    <name>Batman</name>
</person>
```

Comment: Could you define `most effectively`? And, what's wrong with the above example comment?

Comment: I've updated the question to be a bit more specific. I basically have no idea how to add a comment to the root of the xml.

Comment: I apologize. I don't understand what you mean because your XML comment above is perfectly fine. (Comment lines can appear anywhere below the `<?xml ...>` line. But I'm almost sure that's not the issue.)

Comment: Sry, seems like tags were were not enough. I want to do this using groovy programing language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy is perfect language to deal with Xml.

There are a number of different classes that will help you to work with Xml.
Take a look at **groovy.xml** package.

For example to add comment you can use **StreamingMarkupBuilder**:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def inputText = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <name>John</name>
</person>
"""

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(inputText)

xml.name.replaceBody('Batman')

def newXml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    mkp.comment "Your comment"
    mkp.yield xml
}
println XmlUtil.serialize(newXml)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd still like to format the output a bit, to be like my desired output. How do I add a few line breaks in between? I've tried with mpk.yieldUnescaped('\n') and a few other things, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: XmlUtil.serialize(xml) returns string. You can do whatever you want with string. For example add new line symbols before and after comments: XmlUtil.serialize(newXml.toString()).replaceAll('-->','-->\n\n').replaceAll('<!--','\n\n<!--')